# VSTS Xamarin.Android build error

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-devops

I want to setup the build of my Xamarin.Android app in VSTS. 
I received the following error in the Build.Xamarin.Android step: Error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ....\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.25.4.0.2\build\MonoAndroid70\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.targets

I followed the steps as described on the page described in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/vsts/build-release/apps/mobile/xamarin?tabs=vsts

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please check if the files referenced in csproj match the version linked in packages.config?

Comment: Also, does it build fine locally?

Comment: Yes the building is fine on my PC. The version in the referenced project are the same.

Answer (score 1):

> Build.Xamarin.Android step: Error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105.

You need to check two tasks in your build definition:

1. Task : Use NuGet 4.3.0
2. Task : NuGet restore

If any task is missing in your build definition, please add it. If the error persists, please provide the build log.

Comment: These tasks are in nu build definition. So, that's not the problem. I see in my logs all the packages are restored. The problem has something to do with Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.targets

Comment: Sorry, I now discovered you ask for the build log. The build log is too long to send this in this message. Is there an another way to provide you the logs? Thanks for you help. Grtz, Marcel

Comment: You can share the log through online repository. I'll check it next week, sorry for that, doesn't work at weekend.

Comment: I wan't to share my demo VSTS project with you. Please, can you give me your account? I think this is the best way to share my project. Thanks in advance. Marcel

Comment: Sorry, that's against my company's policy to provide personal/company account of VSTS, could you please share the demo or build log on Github?

Comment: That's not neccesary at this moment. I've created a new project. Now I can build my Xmarin project in VSTS without any problems. Thank you for your time. Grtz, Marcel